# Default fetch more pagination or network-only policy in apollo-react issue

Tags: mongoose, graphql, react-apollo

I can not display fixed number of results on the page. Data from query is different because of cache and bigger by fixed number of records from response (graphql request to database is correct).

Fetch policy "network-only" not working as expected: "will never return you initial data from the cache". Fetch policy "no-cache" do not give data.

My Query component:

```
render() {
  return ( 
     <Query query={MOVIES_QUERY}  variables={{skip: skip, limit: limit}} fetchPolicy="network-only">
         {({ data, loading, error }) => {
           // data different by cache
            ...
           // onClick I am changing state
           this.setState()
            ...
         }}
     </Query>
  )
}
```

My query:

```
const MOVIES_QUERY = gql`
   query($skip: Int!, $limit: Int!){
      movies(start: $skip, end: $limit) {
         id
         title
      }
   }
```

Mongoose:

```
Movie.find({}).skip(args.start).limit(args.end);
```

I expect to render component with number of records = limit - skip.

Comment: too many things stripped - `fetchMore`, `updateQuery`, updating variables?

Answer (score 0):

Edit
Ok I'm very sorry, I found that the problem was with my mongoose query limit:

```
Movie.find({}).skip(args.skip).limit(args.limit)
```

Limit is simply my page size (number of records per page)

```
Movie.find({}).skip(args.skip).limit(args.per_page)
```